# How can I assign a random line from a text file to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have a problem with my code.

In order for my program to work, I need to provide a variable with several web page links (YouTube links), because it's a music player. The problem is that the way I have to add the links to the code is very unclean:

```
# This is the variable to which I have to add the values ​​in the form of links
items=(
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVSBLkpO-8"
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y"
)

# Variable "Size", i use "size" to I use this variable to count the number of links
# there are
size=${#items[@]}
randomindex=$(($RANDOM % $size))

mpv ${items[$randomindex]}
```

What I want is to be able to extract all the links from a **text file** and that the code can read them directly from the file.

The problem is that as you can see the variable `size` I use it to count the number of links it has and so with the variable `randomindex` to be able to create a random `"${items[$randomindex]}"` and I'm not sure if it will still work the same if I extract them from a text file.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**
I use an "if" for giving the song name:

```
mpv $(shuf -n1 .MRIndie_links)

CANCION=$(shuf -n1 .MRIndie_links)

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: The Less i Know the Better - Tame Impala" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi
```

But it dont works... why?

Comment: When you call `shuf` twice, you (potentially) get two different lines. Thus, you're using a different name as a `mpv` argument than the one you assign to `CANCION`.

Comment: BTW, always quote your expansions: `mpv "$(shuf -n1 .MRIndie_links)"` with the double quotes will be better behaved when the randomly-chosen line contains glob characters (brackets count!), or quotes, or other surprising content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`shuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html) command for this:

```
$ cat links
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vVSBLkpO-8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y
$ shuf -n1 links
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y
```

In your script, you'd use it like

```
mpv "$(shuf -n1 links)"
```

Comment: You suggestion works... but i have a problem. I updated the question, so you can see what im talking about

Comment: @Newbi3: You have to assign to a variable first and only call `shuf` once: `song=$(shuf -n1 links); mpv "$song"; if [[ $song == blah ]]; then ... fi`

Comment: I think it not works with your suggestion, i tried what you say and the if condition still not working

Answer (score 2):

`while IFS= read -r line...` loop like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

urlfile='/path/to/your/url/file.txt'

# iterate all shuffled lines of your urls
while IFS= read -r url || [[ $url ]]; do
  mpv "$url"
done < <(
  # from shuffled urls of your urlfile
  sort --random-sort <"$urlfile"
)
```

Or without looping with Bash, use `xargs` to invoke mpv with each shuffled url entries as argument.

```
xargs -n 1 mpv < <(sort --random-sort <"$urlfile")
```

Comment: This is much more efficient than calling `shuf -n1` over and over! (One could also use `< <(shuf <"$urlfile")` just as effectively).